# How to fetch data from Plesk10 with asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, hosting, plesk, billing, self-hosting

I am trying to create a end User friendly webpage, which access required information from Plesk10 panel.

I have a reseller webhosting plan. I have administrator rights in my hosting plan. In my hosting i can create new user delete suspend or update etc. I can create a separate plesk panel for the user...

**Now my question is :**

I want to create a page which get the user information from plesk10 panel and give some rights to do few simple tasks, Like add/delete/change password/update there own email accounts, get space usage infromation, create/change ftp connection name or password. and a BILLING / INVOICE / and payment detail

How to fetch this data from Plesk10 and update data to Plesk10

Please give me advice to complete this task. or give me any web link related to this issue.

Thank you

JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API for Plesk documented on their website: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc-guide/index.htm

They have c#, vb.net, and php examples.